# MySQL group duplicates together

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL database which looks like this:

```
 ID      | Name    | Product
 --------+---------+----------
 65644   | Charlie | Beer
 65644   | John    | Beer
 65644   | Jan     | Beer
 65644   | Phoebe  | Beer
 65644   | Shaun   | Beer
```

I would like to output a table using php to look something like this:

```
 ID      |               Name                | Product
 --------+-----------------------------------+----------
 65644   | Charlie, John, Jan, Phoebe, Shaun | Beer
```

Currently I've only been able to output it to look like this first table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just use **[group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)**

```
SELECT ID, group_concat ( Name ORDER BY Name SEPARATOR ', ' ), Product
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID, Product
```